# how to connect oracle database to collection in a solrcloud

Tags: oracle, solr, solrj

I have worked in solr local mode. Now Iam trying to import my tables in oracle database to collection created in solrcloud.How to achieve this?
I surfed a lot but no documents helped much.I want a clear idea of how to index daatabase tables into solrcloud.

Comment: There shouldn't really be a difference in how you do it locally versus how you do it in cloud mode, what have you tried? The only thing you should need to take care of is to upload the DIH configuration to your zookeeper nodes.

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

Comment: How to do that using solrj?